# asp.net core 2 Logger with Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have a asp.net core 2 application where i am trying to log traces using LoggerMessage extension methods.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage). The default trace level is set to trace. I am logging Critical,Errors,Warnings and Information messages. These appear on the console and the debug window. But are not reported to application insights.

I have Added ".UseApplicationInsights()" to the web host builder and added the "_loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Trace);" to the startup. I have also ensure that the app insights key is set in the appsetting.json file.

"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX"
  },
 Can someone help me with what am i missing?

SDK Version
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore - 2.1.1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All - 2.0.5

Comment: `UseApplicationInsights` and `AddApplicationInsights` are mutually exclusive ways to set up Application Insights for your application. You need to choose only one way, in your case, remove `UseApplicationInsights` call in `Program.cs`

Comment: Thanks @twinmind. That helped to resolve the issue. But it was the other way around. We had to remove "AddApplicationInsights". Removing "UseApplicationInsights" had not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @twinmind. That helped to resolve the issue. But it was the other way around. We had to remove "AddApplicationInsights". Removing "UseApplicationInsights" had not helped.